# Is there a way to verify that all model relationships are successfully eager loaded in Sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, eager-loading

I'm familiar with the joinedload and subqueryload options in Sqlalchemy, and I'm using them to query a large result set that's later expunged from the session and cached.

Is there a way to verify that every possible relationship from the top-level model on down is eager-loaded at this point?

Answer (score 1):

The supported way to ensure that you've eager loaded all the relationships you need is to put [`lazy="raise"`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/loading_relationships.html#prevent-lazy-with-raiseload) on all of your relationship. It won't tell you that you did something wrong until you do it, but [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-eafp).

```
children = relationship(Child, lazy="raise")
```

Comment: So, you'll autobmatically get the raise if you expunge the object from the session and then later try to access the relationship.  What the OP is asking for is a way to verify before expunging that all relationships are lazy loaded, or put another way  how can you enumerate all relationships in the graph of relationships starting at a particular model.  I don't think this answer is responsive to the question

Comment: Upvoted because it's still a useful piece of information to know. But @SamHartman is correct, this is not the ~droid~ answer I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The following iterator will iterate over all relationships reachable from a given model.  It yields a tuple of `(model_class, relationship_name)`.  You can modify to look at `prop.lazy` or similar, or use this to construct loader options to lazy load the right things, or whatever seems appropriate.

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect

def recursive_relations(model, already_traversed = None):
    if not already_traversed: already_traversed = set()
    inspection = inspect(model)
    already_traversed.add(model)
    for name, prop in inspection.relationships.items():
        yield (model, name)
        if prop.mapper.class_ not in already_traversed:
            already_traversed.add(prop.mapper.class_)
            yield from recursive_relations(prop.mapper.class_, already_traversed)
```